# where does jpa picks up the method userbyusername as i have not given any implementation and i have checked the inner classes too

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-jpa

In my spring boot project, I am using this starter jpa . i have done all the db related thing in appliction.properties. Project is working fine . I fail to undestand where is this methods defination. We have just defined a abstract method how is this method even working?

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Integer>{
    
    Optional<UserEntity> getUserByUserName(String user);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the magic of JPA Repositories. I don't actually know the details of how it works either, I just know how to use it.

Ultimately, I think it has to do with how Spring proxies interfaces. Spring will create an instance of an interface at runtime. When the methods are named according to the specs, Spring can generate an appropriate method.

Here is a good article that goes into detail on how you can construct the method names to make the query that you want: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries.